# Java fx binding styles

Tags: java, javafx

This is my first post here, so I'm sorry in advance if I did anything wrong or anything is unclear.

In javafx I have a tree table view with about 5 columns and the first column simply displays a string for the name of the object. In the set cell value factory method I simply get the name property for my object as shown below.

```java
column.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Foo, String>, ObservableValue<String>>(){
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Foo, String> row) {
        if (row.getValue().getValue() instanceof Foo){
            final Foo bar = (Foo)row.getValue().getValue();
            return bar.getNameProperty();
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

I want to be able to change the color of this string as shown in the table by binding it to a style property. I have tried changing the string to a Text object but could not bind the style property. Is there a way I could bind the style property to something in the Foo object along the lines of

```
String style = "-fx-text-fill: red"
```

That way whenever I want to programatically change the style, it will be updated in the table as well?

Again, apologies for anything that is unclear!

Answer (score 2):

To affect cell visuals such as style, you need to define a cellFactory (in addition to your cellValueFactory).

One way to accomplish "bind the style property to something in the Foo object" is to:

1. Add to Foo a styleProperty defined as a StringProperty.
2. In the cell provided by the cell factory, as the foo object attached to a cell changes, unbind the cell's styleProperty, then bind the cell's styleProperty to the Foo item's styleProperty.

Then when you modify the styleProperty of a Foo object, the style of the foo display in your TreeTable will automatically change simultaneously.