# Javafx, add style to styleclass using bindings

Tags: java, css, javafx, binding, javafx-8

I want to bind some styles to a `TableCell`'s `StyleClass` when a condition is true, so I tried similar way that the answer shows in this question : [Java fx binding styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216190/java-fx-binding-styles) but it didn't worked, I want something like this what I did with Graphics [Javafx: udpate TableCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695888/javafx-udpate-tablecell).

So here is what I tried:

1.

```
private StringBinding styleBinding;

@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty){
    styleProperty().unbind();
    super.updateItem(item,empty);
    MyRow currentRow = getTableRow().getItem();

    styleBinding = Bindings.when(currentRow.hasStyle())
           .then(currentRow.getStyle())
           .otherwise("");
    styleProperty().bind(styleBinding);
}
```

2.

```
private BooleanProperty styleProperty;

@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty){
    super.updateItem(item,empty);
    MyRow currentRow = getTableRow().getItem();

    styleProperty.bind(currentRow.hasStyle());
    styleProperty.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->{
        if(newValue){
           setStyle(currentRow().getStyle()); // also tried with getStyleClass().add(..);
        } else [
           setStyle(""); // and getStyleClass().remove(...);
        }

}
```

When I tried to put without any condition in `updateItem()` just simply like `getStyleClass().add(currentRow.getStyle());` it worked, with `setStyle(...)` also doesn't work. So maybe I have to use the styleclass somehow, but I have no idea how can I bind the new style to the styleclass when the condition changes or to listen the change. Do you have any idea?

I would like something like: `Bindings.when(condition).then(getStyleclass::add).otherwise(getStyleclass::remove);`

Edit:

```
public String getStyle(){
   return "border";
}
```

the .css file:

```
* {
    my-color: #0e5bd6;
}

.tree-table-cell.border,
.table-cell.border{
    -fx-border-width: 1 5 1 1;
    -fx-border-color: my-color my-color my-color my-color ;
}
```

And of course in `.fxml` file is added in the `styleSheets="border.css"`

Comment: This is really confusing: it's not clear if you are trying to change the inline style, or the style class. What does `MyRow.getStyle()` return: a CSS rule (that could be used as an inline style), or the name of a style class? I think you need to create a [MCVE] to make this understandable.

Comment: I have added the missing part that you required.

Comment: So you are trying to update the style class. That's not a property: it's an observable list, so you can't bind it. You need to do that with listeners.